# How to solve $\int e^{x^{2}} (2x+2x^3)\ln(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is fully explaining. During a recent exam I have been asked to solve

$$\int e^{x^{2}}(2x+2x^3)\ln(x)dx$$

and I literally spent an hour on it. I know that

$$e^{x^{2}}(2x+2x^3)\ln(x)=(\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^{2}})(1+x^2)\ln(x)$$

but I don't know how to go on from there. At the same time, I know that

$$\int 2xe^{x^{2}}\ln(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}e^u\ln(u) - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$$

but this latter is unsolvable. I've been looking for substitutions and partitions (in order to integrate by parts), but without any success. Therefore I would like someone could tell me how to solve this integral.

As plus, I would also be specially thankful of any personal advice about how to intelligently look for a substitution or a partition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I proposed an edit for you to help with the double exponent brackets which you seemed to be struggling with.  You can also do e^{a^b}} which displays as $e^{a^b}$ .

Comment: More than 20 months being a member of this site, with 22 questions asked = time to learn MathJax and post questions that be easily be read.

Comment: Another thing to try is the question sandbox where you can make errors to your heart's content, before publishing them: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts

Comment: Now that the problem is solved, you can delete your useless comment, @DonAntonio. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @toritoverdejo Nop. I think it is important to take into consideration advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute $\int e^{x^2} (2x+2x^3) \, dx = x^2 e^{x^2} + C$, using the substitution $t=x^2$ for example, then use that result to do integration by parts in the integral that you were given.

Comment: With this I found the answer by myself. I just realized I had the stupid habit of looking if the integration can be done by parts only by seeking some derivative in the expression. I never thought "hey, let's see what happens if I take this suspicious part of the expression and I integrate it on its own", which is definitely *a must* to find potential parts to integrate. Well, all this to tell you that your answer was surprisingly useful.

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^ne^{x^2}\ln x)=e^{x^2}\left((nx^{n-1}+2x^{n+1})\ln x+x^{n-1}\right),$$the case $n=2$ gives$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2e^{x^2}\ln x)=e^{x^2}\left((2x+2x^3)\ln x+x\right).$$Thus one antiderivative is $(x^2\ln x-\tfrac12)e^{x^2}$.

Comment: You should know I ignored that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^ne^{x^{2}}\ln x)=e^{x^{2}}((nx^{n-1}+2x^{n+1})\ln x+x^{n-1})$, so I'd like to have an explanation of the process to find the antiderivate. The question is *how to solve*, not *what's the answer*. Of course, your answer is useful and I'm thankful.

Comment: @toritoverdejo I thought I *was* showing you [how to solve it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz). The answer's bound to be of the form $f(x)e^{x^2}\ln x+g(x)$ for some "nice" functions $f,\,g$, where by "nice" I mean they don't, say, include $e^{x^2}$ or $\ln x$ factors of their own. Given the desire for a $2x+2x^3$ factor, you pretty much _have_ to try $f(x)=kx^n$ at that point.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int e^{x^2}(2x+2x^3)\ln x\ dx&=\int 2xe^{x^2}(1+x^2)\ln x\ dx& (\text{let } t=x^2, dt=2x\ dx ) \\
&=\int e^t (1+t) \ln\sqrt t\ dt\\
&=\frac12\int e^t(1+t)\ln t\ dt&(\text{IBP, }\operatorname{D}(\ln t), \operatorname{I}(e^t(1+t))\\
&=\frac12\bigg(te^t\ln t-\int\frac1t te^t\ dt   \bigg)\\
&=\frac12te^t\ln t-\frac12e^t\\
&=\frac12x^2e^{x^2}\ln x^2-\frac12e^{x^2}\\
&=x^2e^{x^2}\ln x-\frac12e^{x^2}\\
&=e^{x^2}\bigg(x^2\ln x-\frac12\bigg)+C
\end{align}

I hope I got that right.

Comment: You did, but late. Thank you for the answer though :)